# What do the numbers inside the dots on the map mean?

Tags: pocket-planes

Once in awhile, I see numbers in the dots on the map. What do they mean? It's not the level of the airport...

Answer (score 9):

It's how many planes are currently landed at that airport. When there's no number on the dot there aren't any planes there. Tap an airport with a number in it to go to one of the planes on the tarmac.

Answer (score -3):

The dots let you know the class of the airport.

Class 1 - Gray
Class 2 - Blue
Class 3 - Red

Comment: Your answer directly contradicts an existing answer.  Providing proof would garner upvotes.

Comment: OP asked about the number in the dot, not the color/level of the dot. That's why your have been down voted on this answer.